# Stuck on getting Yelp API to work with Lat/Long in Android

Tags: android

I'm pretty much on the last step to getting my app to work before I start focusing on the front-end design. As someone who just started programming just last year and haven't made any serious apps before, this is very exciting, but I hit a wall that I need help getting out of. I know this is a stretch but here goes.

I was able to use the google maps API and OSRM API with no problems using the simple URL object from java.net.URL, but that was because the APIs did not require any type of OAuth authentication.

[Link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/)

For Yelp's API, I need to use OAuth and they provide sample code [located here](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/java)

I copied both YelpAPI.java and TwoStepOAuth.java and the search works when I try searching by location name. However, I need to change the code to work with lat/long coordinates.

`https:// www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api`

By going to their Search API documentation, I thought that replacing:

`request.addQuerystringParameter("location", location);`
with

`request.addQuerystringParameter("ll", coordinate);`

where coordinate can be any lat/long coordinate such as

`String coordinate = 34.095287, -118.1270146`

However, that did not work. I'm not sure where to go at this point. I've been stuck on this issue for two days and I'm unable to find any resources online to help me. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to search yelp data by lat, lng I use the below method

```
public String search(String term, double latitude, double longitude) {
    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://api.yelp.com/v2/search");
    request.addQuerystringParameter("term", term);
    request.addQuerystringParameter("ll", latitude + "," + longitude);
    this.service.signRequest(this.accessToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();
    return response.getBody();
  }
```

Now all you just need is to cast your string co-ordinates to double.